# Unexpected routes "groups/2/3?"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have a trouble when I set up some links to groups/:id(groups#show).
I would like users to move to groups/:id when there is the existing group on my system and wrote the code below.

```
 <% if @existing_groups_isbns.include? i.get('ItemAttributes/ISBN') %>
 <%= link_to '既存グループへ', group_path(@existing_groups_ids.each{|id| id}) %>
```

In the first place, I created a group. At that time, it worked.The link was "groups/2".
But the link becomes "groups/2/3" both for the old one and new one when I create a new group afterward, although I want "groups/2" for the old one and "groups/3" for the new one. I have no idea why this happens. Could you tell me why and how to solve this?

☆index.html.erb

```
<h1>検索結果</h1>

<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <th>image</th>
    <th>タイトル</th>
    <th>著者</th>
    <th>出版年</th>
    <th>出版社</th>
    <th>page</th>
    <th>Link</th>
 </tr>
 <% if @items.present? %>
  <% @items.each do |i| %>
    <tr>
      <td> <%= link_to image_tag(i.get('SmallImage/URL'), {:style => 'border: none;'}), i.get('DetailPageURL') %></td>
      <td> <%= link_to i.get('ItemAttributes/Title'), i.get('DetailPageURL') %></td>
      <td> <%= i.get('ItemAttributes/Author') %></td>
      <td> <%= i.get('ItemAttributes/PublicationDate')%></td>
      <td> <%= i.get('ItemAttributes/Publisher') %></td>
      <td> <%= i.get('ItemAttributes/NumberOfPages')%></td>
      <td>
       <% if @existing_groups_isbns.include? i.get('ItemAttributes/ISBN') %>
         <%= link_to '既存グループへ', group_path(@existing_groups_ids.each{|id| id}) %>
       <% else %>
         <%= link_to '新規作成', {:controller => 'groups', :action => 'new', :name => i.get('ItemAttributes/Title'),:author => i.get('ItemAttributes/Author'), :publish => i.get('ItemAttributes/Publisher'), :published => i.get('ItemAttributes/PublicationDate'), :isbn => i.get('ItemAttributes/ISBN'), :page => i.get('ItemAttributes/NumberOfPages'), :imageurl=>i.get('MediumImage/URL')} ,class: "btn btn-midium btn-primary"%>
      <% end %> <!-- if @existing_groups_isbns-->     
      </td>
   </tr>
 <% end %><!-- each do-->
<% else %>
 見つかりませんでした。
 <% end %> 
</table>
```

☆index_controller

```
class IndexController < ApplicationController
 def index
    @keyword = params[:keyword]
    if @keyword.present?
      Amazon::Ecs.debug = true
      res = Amazon::Ecs.item_search(params[:keyword], 
          :search_index => 'All', :response_group => 'Medium')
      @items = res.items
    search_isbns = @items.map{ |isbns| isbns.get('ItemAttributes/ISBN')}
    @existing_groups_isbns = Group.select(:isbn).where(:isbn => search_isbns).map(&:isbn)
    @existing_groups_ids = Group.where(:isbn => search_isbns).map{|g| g.id}
   end
 end
```

Comment: you're passing an array to `group_path`.  Pass only one `group_id` to it.

Comment: Thank you very much. I revised but have yet to make it when I would like to show just one link in a table row.

Answer (score 0):

groups_controlller.rb

```
class GroupsController < ApplicationController
  def add
     @group = Groupe.find(params[:group])
     @group.users.create(current_user)        
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
resources :groups do
  get :add # or patch :add
end
```

view.haml

```
= link_to 'add to #{groupe.name}', add_group_path(@group) #, method: :patch
```